# c++: Dynamic array of my own class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic, resize

I have read some posts about changing the size of an array, but I didn't find something for own classes. What I need is an dynamic array of "region".

**Step One (define the class):**

```
class Region{
private:
    int start;
    int end;
public:
   Region(){
   start=0;
   end=0;
   }
   // some get and set functions
}
```

**Step two (define an emtpy array of region):**

```
Region regions[0];
```

**Step three (add a new region)**

```
// Pseudo-Code
generate a help array with dimension 1 (start is 0)
add old regions values to help (none, because it was empty in the beginning)
add the new region to help
delete the regions array
initilize a regions array with dimension 1 (old dimension+1)
copy help to region
delete help
```

I think step 2 is already incorrect. I would like to get some help with Step 2 and Step 3.

And a bonus (after I understood Step 2 and 3) might be: how to delete an specific indexed region.

Regards Martin

Comment: Dynamic array in `c++` is called `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dynamic array, you are looking for `std::vector<Region>` (see reference at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)). This contains insert, delete and push operations.

You can emulate the behaviour yourself with `new[]` and `delete[]`, but this is not recommended in C++

Comment: Actually, to emulate behavior of `std::vector` (at least with standard allocators), you need also _placement new_ to be involved. Which OP likely does not want to do himself, unless he reads some good books about C++.